# Why cant i implement design library in build.gradle

Tags: android, dependencies

[Whats the error here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfM7M.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfM7M.jpg)

Comment: library versions should be the same as the target SDK version.

Comment: use the [material components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below `material` library it is for `androidx` in place of `design`
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'